# Customer auto connect from URL

Tags: magento2, customer

I need to make my user auto connected when using a specific URL.

I look in the model at `app/code/magento/customer` but can't find what I need.

I suppose there is connection function somewhere, but can't find it.

Do you know if what I want is possible and so how to do it?

Comment: What does it mean 'auto connect'?

Comment: The user come from an other application, so i want to connect him by an URL, with information in the URL